# Travel restrictions after marriage?

Tags: visas, tips-and-tricks, weddings

The couple lives in Germany and do not plan on moving to the USA, or he becoming a US Citizen, but the German part of the couple often does work in NYC and has heard that he has to wait a few months before traveling to the USA - doesn't make sense to me!
Are there restrictions or a waiting period after marrying?

Comment: Were the couple married in the U.S. or in Germany, and what was the visa status of the foreign partner? I'm not saying these things are *necessarily* relevant here, but it is often useful background.

Comment: I think the concern is that the person might be trying to circumvent the regular spousal visa process and its restrictions. I don't know to what extent this is the case in the US (I assume someone more knowledgeable will provide a proper answer) but because family members enjoy special rights once they are within a country, it's more difficult to remove them than other aliens with no connections to the country. That's how you end up with this somewhat paradoxical consequence.

Comment: How would the US border officers know that the German person is married to an American?

Comment: One implicitly guesses that one of partners is american, but it would probably be better if you made that explicit in the question.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, never heard of this waiting period before.

Comment: He maybe confusing the details for a fiance visa, which after marriage the foreign national is not supposed to leave the country for a period of time while applying for their green card.